# Check if two trees are identical

Tags: java, recursion, stack

I've made my own Tree class and I trying to check if two trees are identical. But the problem here is I'm using this call :

```
Tree myTree = new Tree();
Tree mySecondTree = new Tree();
myTree.isIdentical(myTree, mySecondTree);
```

It's kind of odd to pass it this way, I want to pass it this way :

```
myTree.isIdentical(mySecondTree);
```

`isIdentical function :`

```
class Tree<T>{
    T data;
    Tree left;
    Tree right;
    Tree(T data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    public boolean isIdentical(Tree t1, Tree t2){
        if(t1 == t2)
            return true;
        if(t1==null || t2==null)
            return false;
        return (
            (t1.data == t2.data) &&
            (isIdentical(t1.left, t2.left)) &&
            (isIdentical(t1.right, t2.right))
        );

    }
}
```

I tried using Stack, but I'm kind of stuck on this

Comment: Why not use `this`? E.g. `this.data == t2.data`. That way you don't need the first parameter. `this` keyword is an automatic reference to the object which invoked the current running method. Or, you can refer to `data` directly it'll be pointing to data of `t1` anyway.

Comment: By means of merkle trees you'd get a boost on this task.

Comment: the answer you accepted is using recursion, edit your question.

Comment: `isIdentical` should be declared `static`, or it should have only one parameter `otherTree` to compare with the `this` reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you want to execute it this way

```
myTree.isIdentical(mySecondTree);
```

You could do this

```
    public boolean isIdentical(Tree t2){
       Tree t1 = this;
       return isIdentical(t1, t2);
    }

    private boolean isIdentical(Tree t1, Tree t2){
    if(t1 == t2)
        return true;
    if(t1==null || t2==null)
        return false;
    return (
        (t1.data == t2.data) &&
        (isIdentical(t1.left, t2.left)) &&
        (isIdentical(t1.right, t2.right))
    );

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your data-structure allows you to call the modified `isIdentical(Tree<T>)` method in the left and right child nodes after a few checks. Remember that the **parent**, **right-child** and **left-child** are all different Tree node instances in your code.

```
public boolean isIdentical(Tree<T> that) {

    if (this == that)
        return true;

    if (that == null)
        return false;

    //check the equality of the current node's data for both this and that. 
    if (this.data == that.data || (this.data != null && this.data.equals(that.data))) {
        //check the left hand side of the current node for both this and that.
        if ((this.left == null && that.left == null 
                || this.left != null && this.left.isIdentical(that.left))
            //check the right hand side of the current node for both this and that. 
            && (this.right == null && that.right == null 
                || this.right != null && this.right.isIdentical(that.right))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could stay with a recursion and make isIdentical(myTree, Othertree) private. Then wrap it inside a method IsIdentical(otherTree) that calls the method with two arguments suppling this (refrence to the current object) as the first parameter.